# How to read this Dutch salary slip

Tags: taxes, netherlands

I got an offer from a Dutch company and I've received what my salary slip would look like.

I couldn't understand it.

I will post it here and hide the actual values for privacy, I would appreciate if you guide me on the meaning of each entry.

[image]

[image]

Is the number in the red box my net salary?

Many thanks,

Comment: Yes. Do you not have access to a Dutch/English dictionary? Did the online machine translation services fail you?

Comment: You can always ask HR people from the company. I expect they are happy to help

Comment: @phoog translation doesn't work with acronyms

Comment: *Nettoloon* is not an acronym.

Comment: @phoog i know that. Some are acronyms some are not, It doesn't make any sense to **cut** the picture and keep the acronyms. If you have an answer, that's appreciated. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: It's actually much easier to read this with actual values.

Comment: @Gala well, that's my salary, which I'd like to keep it private. However, I agree with you, would you like to put some dummy-but-close-to-real-values data ?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan If William Kinaan is actually your name then it's too late for that but a good solution could be to keep the real values but leave your name out of the question. The reasons I find the values helpful is that you can double check rates and totals so dummy values might not be as helpful.

Comment: @Gala yes I'm William Kinaan, that's my real name. I see your point, but I can't *remove my name of the question*. Sounds like a bottleneck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Nettoloon* is indeed your net salary and more-or-less the amount of money that will be transferred to your bank account.

Assuming your wages haven't been garnished to cover some debt and depending on the applicable collective bargaining agreement (CAO), what can still come in-between includes:

- **Health insurance premiums**, if you are using your employer's collective contract and they are collected directly from your salary (otherwise you'll have to pay that directly to your insurer). Note that insurance premium do not cover the entirety of the healthcare system's costs; besides copayment and deductibles, some of the money also comes from tax-like mandatory contribution marked as WG.HEFF.ZVW (for "*werkgeversheffing zorgverzekeringswet*").
- **Small contributions** to things like coffee machines.
- **Commute costs contribution** (*tegemoetkoming reiskosten woon-werkverkeer*) paid to you tax-free by your employer.
- **Reimbursment for travel costs** and the like, also paid tax-free.

Without getting into the details (as I am not 100% sure about some items), the rest of the things mentioned on your salary slip are taxes and mandatory contributions (e.g. to the statutory old-age and invalidity pension systems). Everything with the word TOESL. (for *toeslag*) is a bonus (and especially calculations related to the "holiday bonus" usually paid in May). ARBEIDSKORT. presumably stands for *arbeidskorting*, a tax credit.

Comment: Thank for answering. Regarding the health insurance point: isn't written above, in one of the rows, that they'll deduct some money for it please ? If no, I'd need to ask a separate question regarding how to make health insurance in the NL

Comment: @WilliamKinaan As I explained, they deduct some money alright, but that's a mandatory contribution to the system in general, not a premium paid to your insurer nor something that would open any right to health insurance coverage. You pay that no matter what but you still need to insure yourself separately. For that, you'll probably need to get a contract from a private insurer as it's how it generally works in the Netherlands.

Comment: Most employers have contracts with some insurers but it is by no means mandatory to go through them, you can choose any other insurer in the market (but you *have* to be insured, you cannot choose to forgo health insurance). It's also possible that your employer offers the possibility to collect the premiums directly from your salary, as a convenience, but that would come after the *nettoloon* line as you have to pay this from your after-tax salary. You'll probably receive some information package about all this on your first day of work.

Comment: What does WAO / IVA / WGA mean?

Comment: @SwatantraKumar Those are different insurances/benefits for people who have been deemed partially or completely unable to work for health/disability reasons. Where have you seen those? If you want more details, you should probably ask a new question…